# Is there any way in JSXGraph to make image not transparent?

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

```
var im = brd.create('image',[urlImg, [function(){return p.X();},function(){return p.Y();}], [3,3] ], {opacity:1});
```

I used this, but the image is still transparent, is there anyway to make it not transparent?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the image is not transparent but other elements are shown on top of the image. The default layer for images in JSXGraph is 0, most other elements are in a higher level. You can specify the layer explicitly during construction:

```
var im = brd.create('image',[
        urlImg, 
        [function(){return p.X();}, function(){return p.Y();}], 
        [3,3] ], 
        {layer:9});
```